# How can I enable ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION?

Tags: vertica, with-clause

I tried the following

```
mip_owner=> SELECT add_vertica_options('OPT', 'ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION');
```

ERROR 4296:  Options not set
HINT:  ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION is not a valid Opt Vertica option

Also after setting the dbdrole I was unable to set it.

```
mip_owner=> set role dbduser;
SET
Time: First fetch (0 rows): 1.481 ms. All rows formatted: 1.491 ms

mip_owner=> SELECT add_vertica_options('OPT', 'ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION');

ERROR 4296:  Options not set
HINT:  ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION is not a valid Opt Vertica option
```

Also there is no current option set

```
mip_owner=> SELECT show_current_vertica_options();

 show_current_vertica_options 
------------------------------
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option appears to only be available in version 7.1+. Verify that you have the correct version (`SELECT VERSION();`).

```
dbadmin=> SELECT add_vertica_options('OPT', 'ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION');
 add_vertica_options
---------------------
 Options Set
(1 row)

dbadmin=> SELECT show_current_vertica_options();
                          show_current_vertica_options
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Opt Vertica Options
--------------------
ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION


(1 row)
```

Comment: got previous version Vertica Analytic Database v7.0.1-3 .